# Qt application with Inno setup : runtime error

Tags: mysql, qt, dll, runtime-error, inno-setup

I'm doing a software with Qt 5.1 and now I want to create a setup with it. So I took Inno setup with the .exe of my application and I linked all the libraries. When I install the app on my computer (Windows 7) it's all right but when I try to install it on an other computer (Xp) I have the error "Runtime error". I don't have any more informations about this error, no code, no log, nothing, so I don't know where this error come from. Maybe it can be usefull to said that my app use MySQL and the lib inpout32.dll.

So my question is, how could I know where this error come from ?

I don't know what else to said about my issue so if you have any more question..

Thanks.

Comment: So the error appears when you start installer-exe or when you start the application after the installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Make sure you have built your application as release.
- Check using [depends](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) wich dlls are used by your app and include them in
  installer.
- If you are building your app with Visual Studio, you may
  have to install redistributable package
- Try to start your app under
  supervision of depends (I think the menu item is called "Profile") It
  may give you a clue which dlls are missing or in which dll the crash
  occurs.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks to take a look to my problem. The application is built as release. I already use the software to check if I have all the libs and it seems ok. I'm using Qt creator to build my app with mingw32. How could I start my app under supervision of depends ? I never used it.

Comment: The thing I really want to know it's how can I have more informations about this error. Because without this it could be anything.

Comment: Download and install dependency walker on both computers. It shows which DLLs are required by DLL/exe to run. Your problem is very likely that your App uses some proper DLLs (probably Qt) and others (probably some windows system DLLs, on which Qt-DLLs rely) not proper. The problem is known as DLL-Hell. So, make sure you provide all DLLs required by your APP in installer.

Comment: I used dependacy walker on both computer. On the first one (Seven) it's said that it can't open around 10 files but the app start fine. On the other one I have 2 "Error opening file." with WER.dll and IESHIMS.dll. Do I have to take those from my computer or do you think I have to install something else ?

Comment: Have you installed VC redisitributable package? Have you tried to start the app using "Profile"? The execution log may give you a clue. The problem with DLLs are, the application loads them by name. 2 DLLs having the same name may be internally different. Calling a function of an incompatible DLL would cause runtime error. So having all DLLs doesn't mean "having all proper DLLs"

Comment: Problem solved. I used OllyDbg to debug and found, thanks to the error within the log, that the lib qwindows.dll was missing. So I created a folder "platforms" in the install folder and added the lib within it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Interesting! Was not aware of that software.